# How to listen for key strokes without Windows Forms .NET

Tags: c#, .net

How can I create a key listener that listens for strokes while a program is running in the background, or as a service, for instance?

I already have a loop running with Thread, and I just need to be able to set and unset key bindings. Everywhere I searched all I got were Windows Forms solutions D:

Comment: ... You want to make a key logger?

Comment: @siva.k To be fair, same techniques used for a key logger could also be used to implement global hotkeys. ;)

Comment: Not a key logger, but logs something else. However I'd like to have some keyboard shortcuts for some important functions.

Comment: I guess it's similar to a keylogger

Comment: You need a window.  How you create one is entirely your choice, you can make it as complicated as you like.

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible without a window.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a *visible* window. Maybe you want this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309.aspx

Comment: Can't you just listen to the message queue for key presses, if all else fails? Isn't that how key loggers generally work? C# has comfortable and built-in ways of doing that, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned "Windows Forms" so I assume you are on Windows. You could register a hook function to accomplish this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx

The function will reside in a DLL that is loaded externally. If you need to communicate with a console or application you will need to handle the IPC yourself.

This will allow you filter *all* keyboards events, even those bound for the system.